# jsp not working on linux ec2

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have set up an Amazon Linux EC2. I am very new to it, but everything I want is almost set up. I have a domain pointed, elastic IP, PHP/Apache/MySQL. I am also wanting to run Java on this instance as well, which I assume is possible. All my php stuff works, but when I hit a .jsp page, it looks like simple HTML.

I log into my instance through the console, and get these:

```
[ec2-user@ip-* ~]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"         
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.3.10.3.29.amzn1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)`

echo $PATH                                       
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin
```

and when I hit my_domain:8080 I get the tomcat page.

So I know Java is installed, and Tomcat is running. What else am I missing?

My .jsp file looks like this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>                                       
<!DOCTYPE html>                                       
<html>                                       
    <head>                                       
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">                                       
        <title>JSP Page</title>                                       
    </head>                                       
    <body>                                       
        <h1><% out.println("Hello World!");%></h1>                                       
    </body>                                       
</html>
```

This is what my browser displays:

`<@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% out.println("Hello World!");%>`

Anyone know what I need to fix this so PHP and JAVA will both work?

Comment: are you sure that you deployed the .jsp to the tomcat webapps folder?

Answer (score 1):

Wow.. yep @fmodos was correct. I've been so use to PHP I dropped the .jsp file in my www folder of apache instead of my webapps folder of tomcat. Der.

I also needed to give give my ec2-user permissions in order to FTP files into it.